# Updating UITableView - wrong cells and same images

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a table of images with little text. How it works:
I have a model, that takes JSON response from Instagram and puts it all into array of dictionaries.
In my method cellForRowAtIndexPath I set the tag of cell to indexpath.row, then start downloading the image (getting url from model) by using dispatch_async.
After image has finished loading, I have a check to compare the tag of current cell and current indexpath.row, and if they are same, image is drawn.
It works fine, until I refresh my model. Simply getting same data reloaded causes weird behavior on table - it shows first three cells as same images. 
How do I fix that?

Here is my cell method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    if (self.loader.parsedData[indexPath.row] != nil)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = nil;

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {

                NSString *url = [self.loader.parsedData[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imageLR"];

                if ([self.cache objectForKey:url] != nil)
                {
                    NSData *imageData = [self.cache objectForKey:url];
                    self.tempImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                }

                else
                {

                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                self.tempImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                [self.cache setObject:imageData forKey:[self.loader.parsedData[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imageLR"]];

                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (cell.tag == indexPath.row)
                    {
                        cell.imageView.image = self.tempImage;
                        [cell setNeedsLayout];
                    }

                    });
            });

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.loader.parsedData[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I have tried putting [tableview reloadData] everywhere, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a problem.
I have used property on tableViewController to hold downloaded data.
So at any time various blocks could write to it at same time and use that pointer for setting images.
What happened on update, several blocks used it at the same time, resulting in same images.
I have switched to using local NSData variable and it works good now.